# R memory.limit() command not able to handle vector allocation in genomic data

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, cluster-computing

I am dealing with large genomic data files. I try to process one with the following R code:

```
dj_annotatedhESC<-annotate(djhESC, Nuc_hESC, "Nuc")
```

**Error: cannot allocate memory of size 5.8 Gb #debilitating error**

The error highlighted in bold is due to the sheer size of the Nucleosome coverage vector. I tried to sort this problem out by using the command: "memory.limit(6000), memory.limit(8000) etc." and requesting different amounts of memory but this does not work.

Although I came up with a temporary solution of reducing the size of the Nucleosome coverage file by taking the best ChIP-Seq reads- Is there a way that I can get around this (i.e. can I somehow request more memory for R, bearing in mind that I am using a ***linux cluster*** computer)?

Comment: Is this a Windows cluster? I have in the past used more memory on a Unix cluster without having to specify a memory limit inside R (and the function is Windows specific at any rate).

Comment: No sorry it's a linux cluster

Comment: In that case you should have gotten a warning when using that function …. Anyway, you need to specify your memory requirement when connecting to the cluster, not inside R.

Comment: great can you maybe post a link to where I might find a decent tutorial for this kind of thing?

Comment: It depends on the cluster. I only know Platform LSF, where you need to specify your resource usage via `-R 'rusage[…]'`.

Comment: ok thank you i thinks I got it workin